# Multi-dimensional summation operator

Tags: summation

For example we could simplify $$\int_{x\in X}\int_{y\in Y}fdxdy$$

To

$$\int_{v\in A}fdv$$

Can we simplify the summation operation $\sum_{i\in \mathbb N}\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_{in}$ in a similar way?

I heard about symbols such as $\sum\oplus$ but I am not sure if they are relavent.

Comment: How about $\sum_{{\bf k}\in S}a_{\bf k}$?

Comment: @caverac I like it but are you sure that this is legit?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Multidimensional_DFT) is an example

Comment: @caverac Which line is that? Btw I am guessing that that something like $\sum_{k\in \mathbb N^2}$ is legit.

Comment: $$\sum_{{\bf n} = {\bf 0}}^{{\bf N} - 1} e^{2\pi i {\bf n}\cdot {\bf k}/{\bf N}}X_{\bf k}
$$